# perl: shuffle value-sorted hash?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

At first sorry for my english - i hope you will understand me.

There is a hash:

```
$hash{a} = 1;
$hash{b} = 3;
$hash{c} = 3;
$hash{d} = 2;
$hash{e} = 1;
$hash{f} = 1;
```

I want to sort it by values (not keys) so I have:

```
for my $key ( sort { $hash{ $a } <=> $hash{ $b } } keys %hash  ) { ... }
```

And at first I get all the keys with value 1, then with value 2, etc... Great.

But if hash is not changing, the order of keys (in this sort-by-value) is always the same.

Question: How can I shuffle sort-results, so every time I run 'for' loop, I get different order of keys with value 1, value 2, etc. ?

Comment: You want to sort it, but have a random order for keys that have the same value, right?

Comment: I tried only shuffle (from List::Util) before "sort" in for loop, but that obviously didnt work as it shuffled whole hash.. Jonathan: yes, thats correct.

Comment: Wait, do you want to randomize the order of the keys returned (after sorted, still keeping the sort-by-value), or the order of keys before you sort by value?

Comment: I want to randomize the order of keys returned.

Comment: @gibson: see below, it's not the most elegant or perlized, but it's the logic

Comment: `sort` keeps the order of items that compare identically. It does this so that if you sort an already sorted list, it leaves them in the same order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure I well understand your needs, but is this ok:

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my %hash;
$hash{a} = 1;
$hash{b} = 3;
$hash{c} = 3;
$hash{d} = 2;
$hash{e} = 1;
$hash{f} = 1;

for my $key (sort { $hash{ $a } <=> $hash{ $b } } shuffle( keys %hash  )) {
    say "hash{$key} = $hash{$key}"
}
```

Comment: That and the example with multi-level sorting (by TLP) worked :). Thanks guys!

Comment: @M42, If you want a fair sort, you'll need to use `use sort 'stable';`. Without it, `sort` can corrupt the result of `shuffle`.

Comment: @ikegami Surely you jest. `shuffle` finishes and returns the list to `sort` before any of its values are even used.

Comment: @TLP, huh??? I can't figure out what you're trying to say, but I do no jest. `perl -E'use sort "_quicksort"; say for ( sort { 0 } "aa".."zz" )[0..5];'` sm bg mw yy mg ri

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add another level of sorting, which will be used when the regular sorting method cannot distinguish between two values. E.g.:

```
sort { METHOD_1 || METHOD_2 || ... METHOD_N } LIST
```

For example:

```
sub regular_sort {
    my $hash = shift;
    for (sort { $hash->{$a} <=> $hash->{$b} } keys %$hash) {
        print "$_ ";
    };
}
sub random_sort {
    my $hash = shift;
    my %rand = map { $_ => rand } keys %hash;
    for (sort { $hash->{$a} <=> $hash->{$b} ||
        $rand{$a} <=> $rand{$b} } keys %$hash ) {
        print "$_ ";
    };
}
```

Comment: Your code is buggy for two reasons. 1) When using "misbehaving" comparisons such as this, the results of documented as *undefined*, so `sort` is allowed to return garbage, repeated elements, missing elements, etc. 2) Even if `sort` doesn't return garbage, it won't be a fair sort. The result will be weighed. I posted the fix as an answer.

Comment: @ikegami I see no reference to numeric comparisons or the use of functions causing undefined results in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html). Please provide some documentation or explanation on those statements.

Comment: It's at the bottom. "The comparison function is required to behave. If it returns inconsistent results (sometimes saying `$x[1]` is less than `$x[2]` and sometimes saying the opposite, for example) the results are not well-defined."

Comment: As for explanation of (2), sorry, I don't have the details, but I have seen both the theory and practical experiments showing that `sort { rand <=> rand }` does not result in randomly sorted list.

Comment: @ikegami Ok, I see now.. if a < b < c, but a > c that can cause confusion. Point taken. The values must be static. Still, how are the results weighed?

Comment: @ikegami Fixed. Though it took me a while to figure out what you meant. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

To sort the keys by value, with random ordering of keys with identical values, I see two solutions:

```
use List::Util qw( shuffle );
use sort 'stable';
my @keys =
   sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} }
   shuffle keys %hash;
```

or

```
my @keys =
   map $_->[0],
   sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }
   map [ $_, $hash{$_}, rand ],
   keys %hash;
```

---

The `use sort 'stable';` is required to prevent `sort` from corrupting the randomness of the list returned by `shuffle`.

---

The above's use of the [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) is not an attempt at optimisation. I've seen people use `rand` in the compare function itself to try to achieve the above result, but doing so is buggy for two reasons.

When using "misbehaving" comparisons such as that, the results are documented as being *undefined*, so `sort` is allowed to return garbage, repeated elements, missing elements, etc.

Even if `sort` doesn't return garbage, it won't be a fair sort. The result will be weighed.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two functions for ascending and decending order and use them accordingly like

```
sub hasAscending {
   $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b};
}

sub hashDescending {
   $hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a};
}

foreach $key (sort hashAscending (keys(%hash))) {
   print "\t$hash{$key} \t\t $key\n";
}

foreach $key (sort hashDescending (keys(%hash))) {
   print "\t$hash{$key} \t\t $key\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to randomize looping through the keys.

Perl, does not store in sequential or sorted order, but this doesn't seem to be random enough for you, so you may want to create an array of keys and loop through that instead.

First, populate an array with keys, then use a random number algorithm (1..$#length_of_array) to push the key at that position in the array, to the array_of_keys.

---

If you're trying to randomize the keys of the sorted-by-value hash, that's a little different.

[See Codepad](http://codepad.org/DJpRS7Vj)

```
my %hash = (a=>1, b=>3, c=>3, d=>2, e=>1, f=>1);
my %hash_by_val;

for my $key ( sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash ) { 
   push @{ $hash_by_val{$hash{$key}} }, $key;
}


for my $key (sort keys %hash_by_val){
   my @arr        = @{$hash_by_val{$key}};
   my $arr_ubound = $#arr;

   for (0..$arr_ubound){
      my $randnum = int(rand($arr_ubound));
      my $val     = splice(@arr,$randnum,1);
      $arr_ubound--;
      print "$key : $val\n";                    # notice: output varies b/t runs
   }
}
```

Comment: Re your first paragraph: It's not by design. It's a side affect of a hash. While the order isn't known, it isn't random either. It can even be predictable. For example, run `perl -E'%h = map { $_ => 1 } qw( a b c d ); say keys %h;'` a few times.

Comment: @ikegami: your word is gold, so I'm not doubting you, but isn't that by design in order to reduce seek time?

Comment: If it was done to reduce the seek time of a hash table, it means one could have an ordered hash table at the cost of increasing the seek time (whatever that is) of a hash table. But it's impossible to have an ordered hash table, so it wasn't done to reduce the seek time of a hash table. Again, it's simply a side effect of using a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: Maybe you're talking about the change that went into 5.8.1. Since then, the elements of a hash can be reassigned to new buckets (by perturbing the hashing algorithm) if too many elements end up in the same bucket. This done in order to prevent fetches from and insertions into that particular hash from become slow. The order returned by `keys` is almost always affected as a side-effect.

Comment: @ikegami: couldn't you have an ordered hash, using Tie::Hash?  Regardless, no I was thinking hashes were formulated similarly to relational db lookup tables, where the order isn't finite.  It seems that I was wrong and have changed my answer.

Comment: I don't know what kind of data structure Tie::Hash uses, but it cannot be a hash table. Tie::Hash shows that it's possible to have ordered *associative arrays*, not hash tables. A hash table is a specific kind of associative array. The discussion is a little confusing because modules like Tie::Hash makes it possible to have a hash variable that's not a hash table.